# Searching using Apache Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Apache lucene to search for a string within a file . What kind of parsing of does lucene use. If I search for obama it doesn't return results with Presobama while it returns results for #Obama. Can anyone tell me why? I am using TextField.

```
         StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_44);

        //  Code to create the index
        Directory index = new RAMDirectory();

        IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44, analyzer);

        IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);
        addDoc(w, finalstep);

        w.close();
                    String querystr =  search;

        //  The \"title\" arg specifies the default field to use when no field is explicitly specified in the query
        Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_44, "title", analyzer).parse(querystr);

        // Searching code
        int hitsPerPage = 10;
        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.create(hitsPerPage, true);
        searcher.search(q, collector);
        ScoreDoc[] hits = collector.topDocs().scoreDocs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analyzer dictates how the text is separated into tokens.  You are using `StandardAnalyzer`.

`StandardAnalyzer` tried to separate the stream into words, generally.  The rules it uses to do this is are specified in full in [Unicode Standard Annex #29](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/), but speaking very roughly:  It separates tokens at spaces and punctuation.

This "#Obama" becomes "obama".  The "#" will be removed in analysis.  "Presobama" will become "presobama".  The parsing rules present don't know anything about the term "presobama", and have no reason to conclude it should be treated as more than one word.

There are a number of approaches to getting looser matching.  A few possibilities:  You can use [Wildcard queries](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Wildcard_Searches), use an [NGramTokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenFilter.html) to index ngrams of the tokens, or if you just have a few such troublesome terms, you could specify synonym replacements using a [SynonymFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/synonym/SynonymFilter.html).